# Gstreamer gst-launch-1.0: symbol lookup error: gst-launch-1.0: undefined symbol: _gst_date_time_type

Tags: 14.04, gstreamer

Hi everyone I installed gstreamer on ubuntu and whenever I try to execute some commands in terminal I get :

```
gst-launch-1.0: symbol lookup error: gst-launch-1.0: undefined symbol: _gst_date_time_type
```

I tried to remove gstreamer-1.0 but it removes ubuntu-desktop and other applications.
How can I fix this ? I mean how can I properly remove it and install latest version of gstreamer which is working(I tried getting 1.4 but for some reason when I type gst I only see 1.0 version and 0.10)?Is there any tutorial for this ? Also where should I start with learning about gstreamer(I would be glad if you could point me to good resources for python)?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Running this command solves problem for me:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Got it from [[Bug 740014] gst-plugins-base-1.4.4 make fails (undefined symbol:_gst_date_time_type)](http://gstreamer-bugs.narkive.com/e50Lbo8m/bug-740014-new-gst-plugins-base-1-4-4-make-fails-undefined)

Comment: For the next time, please also add a short description on what exactly your commands are doing. Thank you! :-) Oh, and welcome to AskUbuntu.com, of course.